# On Pharo 11, is it possible to programatically change the traits of a defined class?

Tags: traits, smalltalk, pharo

On an already created class `MyClass` that subclasses `Object`, it is possible to execute `MyClass subclass: SomeNewClass` to change it's superclass.

It is possible to make something similar to traits so that I can add or remove them from `MyClass`?